# vaadin textArea fraola editor

Tags: javascript, image, textarea, vaadin, clipboard

I try to use fraola editor in vaadin. Fraola editor is a richText javascript component that allow copy image from clipboard easely. In vaadin I just insert the vaaadin textArea Widget and call javascript function $("#richtext").fraolaEditor()...
On the client side it works perfectly but on the server side, the textArea stay empty. I tried to fill the textArea by javascript : on client the textAreain fiiled but stay empty on the server side.... 
every help is welcome

the code : 
        vl.addComponent(getRtarea());

```
    String fraola = "var liste = ''; " 
            + "         $(function() {"
            + "         $('#richText').froalaEditor({"
            + "         enter:$.FroalaEditor.ENTER_P," 
            + "         toolbarButtons:['insertFile','insertImage', 'fullscreen', '|', 'undo', 'redo' , '|', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'color', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'outdent', 'indent', 'clearFormatting', 'insertTable', 'html'],"
            + "         fileUploadURL: 'uploadFile'," 
            + "         imageUploadURL: 'uploadFile',"
            + "         pastedImagesUploadURL: 'uploadFile',  " 
            + "         language: 'fr'"
            + "         }).on('froalaEditor.blur', function(){"
            + "             $('#richText').val($('.fr-element').text()).focus();"
            + "             alert($('#richText').val());"
            + "         })"
            + "         ;});";

    Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(fraola);
```

and getRtarea() :

```
public TextArea getRtarea() {
if (_rtarea == null) {
    this._rtarea = new TextArea();
    _rtarea.setId("richText");
    _rtarea.setSizeFull();
}
return _rtarea;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. It was exactly what I needed. Have a good day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is most likely that the `TextArea` widget only listens for user-originated value change events, but it doesn't react if its value is changed from JavaScript.

You could instead use one of the available RPC mechanisms for sending the new value directly to the server instead of passing it through an existing component. For a standalone integration, you can use the mechanism described in https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/ExposingServerSideAPIToJavaScript.html. Alternatively, you can create a regular JavaScript component based on https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/IntegratingAJavaScriptComponent.html and https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/UsingRPCFromJavaScript.html.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying to use is not the preferred one for integrating JavaScript components in Vaadin. The String fraola, would be send each time you call execute(fraola), this will create excess overhead when done often. In your case you need also state object. See more information about creating JavaScript component here:

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/IntegratingAJavaScriptComponent.html